# How to fix Invalid JSON payload error from the Google Ads API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm trying to pull a report from the Google Ads API into Google sheets and I can't get the API to recognize my query as a query

Here's the code and error I'm getting:

```
    function basicReport() {
  var query = {
    "query" : "SELECT campaign.name, campaign.status FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id"
  };
  
  var body = JSON.stringify(query);
  
  var head = {
    'Developer-token' : "<Dev token>",
    'login-customer-id' : <Manager ID>,
    'Authorization' : "Bearer <Auth token>",
  };

var options = {
  'method' : 'POST',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'headers' : head,
  'payload' : body,
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true
};
  
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://googleads.googleapis.com/v4/customers/<Customer ID>/googleAds:searchStream', options);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

But I constantly get the error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"query\":\"SELECT campaign.name, campaign.status FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id\"}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"query\":\"SELECT campaign' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"query\":\"SELECT campaign.name, campaign.status FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id\"}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"query\":\"SELECT campaign' could not be found in request message."
```

I've run the query in OAuth playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) and it worked there, so I know the query is ok.

I've tried passing the body as an object not a string, but then I get a 500 error.

Comment: You will be surprised (but probably already solved it a long time ago), but the problem is with the `content-type` option. There is no such option - the correct one is `contentType`, otherwise the payload type defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You were also correct to stringify the payload - it is always passed as a string. But when the content-type header is set to default (urlencoded), `UrlFetchApp` allows you to pass an object and stringifies it under the hood, but to a query, resulting in Ads API server being unable to cope with the payload (hence the 500 error)

Comment: It does work with content-type (possibly with both? But definitely with content-type). I did solve it way back, so have posted the full solution below. Thanks for reminding me to follow up!

Comment: That's strange, the parameter couldn't have worked correctly (unless the API also accepts a form-encoded body, which I, frankly, did not test). Re: solution - you can definitely remove the "query" part - it does not matter, in JS there is 0 difference between quoted and unquoted keys - and they are stringified the same. I think the solution works because you moved the content-type to headers - it is a valid header (basically, `contentType` option sets this header under the hood). Dev token capitalization might've also contributed to the issue - it seems like the API is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks! I've just tested and you're right, contentType is set in options, Content-Type is set in headers. Setting either makes it work, but they are not interchangeable.
Also tested the quotes on "query" and capitalization on developer-token - neither matters.

Comment: Glad you checked - everything as expected then. Quotes 100% do not matter by spec, `contentType` spelling matters because this is a parameter, and HTTP headers are case-insensitive by definition (although since user code usually interprets them, I am always trying to follow the exact capitalization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for this - I did solve it.

When set in the header, Content-Type has a dash, when set in the options, contentType does not.

```
function basicReport() {
     var query = {
        "query" : "SELECT campaign.name, campaign.status FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id"
     };
  
     var body = JSON.stringify(query);
  
     var head = {
        'developer-token' : "<Dev token>",
        'login-customer-id' : "<Manager ID>",
        'authorization' : "Bearer <Auth token>",
        'accept' : 'application/json'
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     };

    var options = {
        'method' : 'POST',
        'headers' : head,
        'payload' : body,
        'muteHttpExceptions' : true
    };
  
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://googleads.googleapis.com/v4/customers/<Customer ID>/googleAds:searchStream', options);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);

    Logger.log(data);
```